# Django API Query of 2198 Items takes almost 6min how can i improve the speed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to query my whole table.

This is my view and serializer:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def autofill_api(request):
    items = Product.objects.all()
    print(items)
    serializer = AutoFillSerializer(items, many=True)
    
    return Response(serializer.data)

class AutoFillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # integrating the foreignkey Brand_Name into the serializer 
    brand_name = serializers.CharField(source='brand.brand')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = __all__
```

**Problem**

The Query takes almost 6min. These are the infos the Django Debug Toolbar gives me.

- 2198 SQL Queries
- 376888.26ms

Are there any options to make this query faster?
In the future i will use Django cache_page decorator.
But for the case when my database is updated i don't want the user to wait 6min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the data of the brand with it, with [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) so:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def autofill_api(request):
    items = Product.objects.select_related('brand')
    serializer = AutoFillSerializer(items, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

> **Note**: Especially for Django REST API views, it is better to work with class-based views since it can automate a lot, like injecting a context in the serializer, easily checking (object)permissions. While one can work with a function-based view, it often does not pay off to do so, especially for "basic scenario" views.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thx a lot. I tried it as class-based view as well. 
#class AutoFillAPIView(APIView):
    #def get(self, request):
        #items = Product.objects.select_related('brand')
        #serializer = AutoFillSerializer(items, many=True)
        #return Response(serializer.data)

But the function-based view was 1 sec faster in this scenario.

Comment: @HectorDevough: the idea is not to make an `APIView` yourself, but subclass `ListAPIView` and only specify the `queryset` and `serializer_class`.